# regex_search() return false for positive lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am attempting to use the `regex_search` function in C++11 and my code is not finding the string as I would expect.

```
    std::string regexString = "(?<=settings1)(.*)(?=;)";
    std::regex rgx(regexString);
    std::smatch match;
    std::string settingValue;


    if (std::regex_search("setting1=hellowSettingsWorld;", match, rgx)){
        // match fond
    settingValue = match[1];
        cout << "string found "  << settingValue << endl;
    }else{
    cout << "string not found " 
    }
```

I tested this regex out on regex101 and it tells me it should  find the string "=hellowSettingsWorld"

https://regex101.com/r/nU7qK5/1

however the `std::regex_search()` always returns false?

not sure if i am using the `regex_search` function incorrectly or if there is something wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: simply use: `settings1(.*)(?=;)` or `settings1(.*);`, the lookbehind is not available in ECMAscript regex. (with regex101, you should use the javascript mode for C++). If you really need a more advanced regex engine, use libboost.

Comment: thanks! appreciate the response, but it looks like neither of those suggestions worked. the regex_search function is still returning false. all though i do see that when I switched to javascript in regex101 why they are correct....

Comment: @Matt The string you're trying to match contains `setting1` but your pattern has `settings1` instead.

Comment: @Matt: When you switch to JavaScript on regex101, note that the status is ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

C++ `<regex>` implements according to ECMAScript (a.k.a. JavaScript) `RegExp` with a small extension to support POSIX character classes. Since ECMAScript `RegExp` doesn't support look-behind, C++ `<regex>` also doesn't support the syntax.

As [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) suggested, use Boost library if you want more fancy regex features.